# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'ViewController' & Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Tags: swift, coreml

I'm a beginner iOS developer, and I'm trying to build an image classification app in Swift. However, I encountered two errors that I don't know how to solve.

1st error is on the `guard let strongSelf = self { return }` line, and it says:

> "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'ViewController'"

2nd error is on the `return request` line, and it says

> "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"

```
 var request: VNCoreMLRequest {
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Fruit().model) else {
        fatalError("Can't load model")
    }

    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: { (request, error) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        if let error = error {
            print("Error making request")
        } else {
            strongSelf.process(request: request)
        }

        return request

    })
}
```

How can I fix these errors? Thank you!

Comment: What you are attempting is impossible. You cannot write a computed property `var request: VNCoreMLRequest {` whose value is obtained asynchronously by performing a VNCoreMLRequest over the network. That would require time to run backward.

Comment: We need a lot more context.  Show more code of the containing class so we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

1st error:

Add `[weak self]` capture group

```
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: { [weak self] (request, error) in
```

2nd error:

Cannot be resolved because you can't return something from a closure which doesn't have a return value. A computed property including an asynchronous task is impossible anyway.